# PROC EXPORT outfile row 2

Tags: sas

I'm trying to export the column names of a sas data to a xlsx file but need the data to be copied starting in the 2nd row of the excel file. What I have right now:

```
    PROC EXPORT DATA= mylib.test
    outfile = "exceltobemodified.xlsx"
    dbms = excel replace;
    sheet = "test1";
    range = "test1$A2:BE2000";
    run;
```

However, I get an error indicating that the RANGE statement is not supported and is ignored in Export procedure

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may need to specify the range. Do you need the variable names in the second row. If you need formatting consider looking at ods excel

Comment: it seems like RANGE statement is not supported in the export procedure

Comment: Why exactly do you need the data to start a row 2? I'm trying to understand the practicality of the matter.

Comment: we're a using a template that has information that cannot be modified in the first row. The column names are in the second row. The program is run periodically so any "manual" changes are not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Try the data set option FIRSTOBS.

```
PROC EXPORT DATA= mylib.test (firstobs=2)
outfile = "exceltobemodified.xlsx"
dbms = excel replace;
run;
```

Edit: If by"starting in the 2nd row" you mean to output the data without the variable names, then you have to use PUTNAMES=NO;

```
PROC EXPORT DATA= mylib.test
outfile = "exceltobemodified.xlsx"
dbms = excel replace;
PUTNAMES=NO;
run;
```

Answer (score -1):

Load your table with a blank row as first row. Try writing the table to excel file then. It should work.

```
Proc sql
   insert into test
   values('',.,'')
 quit; 
Proc sort data=test;
 by _all_;
run; 
Options missing='';
proc export data=test outfile='/home/libname/new.xlsx'
dbms=excel replace;
putnames=no;
run;
```

Comment: There are much more efficient ways to add a blank row at the beginning of a file.